# Исключение в ucrtbased.dll и callback

Tags: c++, visual-c++

В `Windows 10` что-то не так, `ucrtbased.dll` плюется исключениями:

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x542FF4E9 (ucrtbased.dll) в some.exe: 0xC000041D: Во время обратного вызова пользователя обнаружено необработанное исключение.

```
#if !_WIN64
#define swinp SetWindowLong
#define gwinp GetWindowLong
#define WINC_PTR GWL_USERDATA
#else
#define swinp SetWindowLongPtr
#define gwinp GetWindowLongPtr
#define WINC_PTR GWLP_USERDATA
#endif // _WIN64
```

Код в котором происходит исключение:

```
LRESULT window_base::p_msg_proc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    window_base* self_;
    if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        swinp(hWnd, WINC_PTR, LONG(LPCREATESTRUCT(lParam)->lpCreateParams));
        return TRUE;
    }

    self_ = reinterpret_cast<window_base*>(gwinp(hWnd, WINC_PTR));

    if (!self_)
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    // Именно тут
    return self_->msg_proc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Объявление `msg_proc` это чисто виртуальная ф-ция
protected:

```
virtual LRESULT WINAPI msg_proc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) = 0;
```

Номер сообщения при котором выбрасывается исключения: `WM_CANCELMODE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следует избавиться от этих дефайнов, они совершенно ни к чему. Установка указателя на пользовательские данные сделана неправильно, указатель кастуется в тип `LONG`, тем самым потенциально портится.

```
if(WM_NCCREATE == uMsg)
{
    assert(0 != lParam);
    auto const & params{*reinterpret_cast<::LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam)};
    auto const old_value{::SetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterptre_cast<::LONG_PTR>(params.lpCreateParams))}
    assert(0 == old_value);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Также проверьте код, который присваивает значение полю `lpCreateParams`.

Comment: Присваивается прямо в `CreateWindowEx`